# How to drop data in a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe A like this

```
    user_id sku_id    time
0   56804   75906   2016-02-01 00:10:48
1   56804   75906   2016-02-01 08:36:59
2   56805   75906   2016-02-01 08:36:59
3   56806   81256   2016-02-01 00:08:15
……
```

and then I have another dataframe B like this:

```
    user_id sku_id        
0   56804   75906
1   56806   81256   
……
```

I want to select the samples in dataframe A with the (user_id, sku_id) is not in dataframe B. How to do it efficiently? cause My data is relatively huge, and I do it in my PC with the limited memory.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `indicator`, [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering and then remove helper column with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
       .query('_merge == "left_only"')
       .drop('_merge', 1)
print (df)
   user_id  sku_id                 time
2    56805   75906  2016-02-01 08:36:59
```

Another solution:

```
x = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1['user_id'], df1['sku_id']])
y = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2['user_id'], df2['sku_id']])
inter = x.difference(y)
df1 = df1.set_index(['user_id', 'sku_id']).loc[inter].reset_index()
print (df1)
   user_id  sku_id                 time
0    56805   75906  2016-02-01 08:36:59
```

Comment: jez you are so fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df1.append(df2)

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id','sku_id'],keep=False)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: In case there is a entry in `df2`, which is not in `df1`, that entry is appended, but then not dropped since it is not a duplicate.
A workaround for this problem could be to append `df2` twice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it:
1) Using isin you can remove the desired columns. But you will have to merge the two columns to perform this operation:

```
A["id"] = str(A["user_id"])+"_"+str(A["sku_id"])
B["id"] = str(B["user_id"])+"_"+str(B["sku_id"])
l = list(B["id"])
A2 = A[~A["id"].isin(l)]
```

2) Create another field in B dataframe which is 1. You can merge the two dataframes using all condition and drop the fields which have 1 as value

```
B["unique"] = 1
A2 = A.merge(B,on=["user_id","sku_id"],how="outer")
A2 = A2[A2["unique"]!=1]
```

Let me know if this helps